# Hadamard product equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

I'm struggling with the following task in my thesis: given $\mathbf{M}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and some vector $\mathbf{w}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, I would like to find some vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that would fulfil:
$$
\mathbf{v}\circ(\mathbf{Mv})=\mathbf{w}
$$
where $\circ$ denotes elementwise (Haramard) product. In other words, this can be rewritten as:
$$
w_i=v_i [\mathbf{Mv}]_i=v_i \sum_j M_{i, j}v_j
$$
Even though $\mathbf{M}$ has all the nice properties in the world (strictly diagonally dominant $\rightarrow$ invertible, symmetric, positive semi-definite) I cannot solve this analytically (thankfully, I have already written a numerical algorithm). Is it known to be a sort of problem that cannot be reduced to canned linear algebra algorithms, like inverting or eigenvectors? Or am I missing something? Every time I go down the rabbit hole of rewriting this, I end up with some other matrix $\mathbf{M}'$ and another vector $\mathbf{w}'$ and all I need to do is to find some $\mathbf{v}'$ such that $\mathbf{v}'\circ(\mathbf{M}'\mathbf{v}')=\mathbf{w}'$...

EDIT: Maybe it's worth noting, that I have already reduced this to solving $\mathbf{v}\circ(\mathbf{Mv})=\vec{1}$.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me if you look properties of $M$ that allow you to solve the equation analytically or if your $M$ has exactly the properties you mention. Also, could you please tell how you solve that numerically?

Comment: If $M$ is the identity matrix, then $v\circ v=(v_1^2,\dots , v_n^2)$ for every $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, so you cannot solve your equation for $w$ that has negative coordinates. Why do you expect to be able to find $v$ for every $w$ in the general case?

Comment: My problem stems from a certain application in my thesis, regarding optimization of some bookmaker's action on the market. $\mathbf{M}$ is a given matrix that comes from the parameters and I can guarantee it is symetric, invertible etc. $\mathbf{w_i}$'s are actually $\mathbf{p_i}$'s (probabilites), so they are greater than zero and sum to $1$.

Comment: My numerical algorithm is placed one layer above - if I offer prices $a_i$ to my clients in some setting $A$ and they choose to buy nothing, then I can prove that those prices $a_i$ are optimal in some other setting $B$. For now, I just gradient-descent the $a_i$ prices in the setting $A$ to achive $\Delta=\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some better solution methods, but you can always cast the problem into an unconstrained minimisation of the degree-4 polynomial $f(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(v_i\sum_{j=1}^nm_{ij}v_j-w_i\right)^2$ over $\mathbb R^n$. The original equation is considered solvable if the minimum value of $f$ is close to zero (within a pre-specified tolerance). Just use any unconstrained optimisation package to your liking.